# Error with `ssh -Y`, error in locking authority file

Tags: ssh, x11

I am using X11 over the secure shell with the "trusted forwarding" flag, i.e.using trusted forwarding with `ssh -Y`

Today I have been receiving the following error:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/users/USERNAME/.Xauthority
```

To actually try to use X11 with an application, I get the error

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication
```

It's difficult to find exact documentation regarding what is going on here. Any advice?

EDIT:

For future users: when this happens, it appears either (A) you are out of disk space or (B) the file permissions are wrong.

It looks like I had a combination of the two. Issue resolved.

Comment: What is the user, group and permissions on the directory `/home/users/USERNAME` and the file `/home/users/USERNAME/.Xauthority` (on the remote host)?

Comment: @MurrayJensen I think I see where you're coming from
It appears `/home/users/USERNAME/.Xauthority` doesn't exist, or is not writable by `USERNAME`. 
How do I change this?

Comment: Presumably `/home/users/USERNAME` is the home directory for user `USERNAME` so if it is not owned by them you are going to have a lot of other problems (which is the only way you could not create the file if it didn't exist) ... my guess is that the user's `.Xauthority` file will be owned by `root` - I vaguely recall a bug somewhere (in `openssh`??) that causes this ownership problem but can't remember the details ... just remove the `.Xauthority` file for that user (on the remote host)

Comment: @MurrayJensen I deleted the `.Xauthority` file. Unfortunately, I get a similar error.

Comment: was it owned by root?

Comment: @MurrayJensen Yes

Comment: sorry, not sure how to fix this ... try creating an empty `.Xauthority` file owned by the user after removing the one owned by root.